(Вопрос про JavaScript) Как изменить название массива? И как изменить название массива внутри большего массива?
Ну то есть допустим
var chernovik = [3, "stroka", ["odin", "dva", 3.4], 9]
В итоге когда я вбиваю в консоль chernovik, он мне выдаёт:
(4) [3, 'stroka', Array(3), 9]
То есть он этот массив внутри массива почему-то называет Array(3). Почему именно это слово и как мне этот массив внутри массива переименовать например в "chisla"?
И как при необходимости переименовать главный массив, в котором это всё находится?

У массивов нет имён. Имена есть у переменных, а у массивов (и вообще значений) имён нет.

@Stanislav Volodarakiy Но почему тогда он даёт внутреннему массиву имя Array(3)?

Это не имя, это он так сокращает значение, чтобы всё вместе в строку влезло. В консоли рядом есть стрелочка. Кликните её, покажутся значения во вложенном массиве.

почему тогда он даёт внутреннему массиву имя Array(3) - потому что так захотел разработчик браузера. В спецификации не регламентировано как именно console.log должен отображать переданные данные, поэтому вывод может быть разным в разных браузерах, и в разных версиях одного браузера.

У массивов нет имён. Имена есть у переменных, а у массивов (и вообще значений) имён нет.
То что вы видите вы консоли Chrome/Chromium:

Раскройте стрелочку слева чтобы увидеть подробности:

Переименовать массив нельзя, но можно создать новую переменную указывающую на тот же массив:
var drugoe_imya = chernovik

Можно создать новую переменную со значением второго элемента массива:
var chisla = chernovik[2]


Ну в теории же можно, это же название класса

@OliverPatterson, у ТС трудности с понятиями имени и значения переменной. А вы про классы заговариваете. Приходите через месяц.

@OliverPatterson, чисто технически, это скорее значение из свойства с именем Symbol.toStringTag, в классах, в качестве значения, ему по умолчанию присваивается имя класса, но в принципе может быть присвоена любая строка. Однако, в выводе console.log, в зависимости от реализации, может использоваться что-то другое.
